# Dealing with negative work

Tags: work, conventions

Dumb question, I'm working with vector fields right now, and one question on here tells me to assume an object can take on three paths from a to b. (paths not listed here) for times in [0,1] Now assume the object must move from a to b and back to a. Additionally, the object can not cover the same path twice . What is the path that leads to the greatest amount of work. Now, here's my issue: all three paths lead to positive work from a to b and negative work from b to a. So, is there a special way to deal with negative work, or should i just add the negative work and positive work together to get the total amount of work done on that path? ( of course the later would imply zero work in some cases)

Answer (score 2):

The total work is simply the algebraic sum of the negative and positive work.